# How to change my name in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

When I look at the settings of one of my calendars in Google Calendar, it says Calendar Owner. And the string that comes after that looks hideous. It goes something like this:

```
"my.name@gmail.com" <my.name@gmail.com>
```

In addition, if I look at the XML of a shared calendar, the author tag looks like this:

```
 <author>
   <name>my.name@gmail.com</name>
   <email>my.name@gmail.com</email>
 </author>
```

I've been looking for ages now, but I simply can't figure out how to change that name. And I really want to, cause it looks wrong and ugly. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You want to change Calendar name or calendar owner?

Comment: @Raystafarian The name of the owner. As you can see in both the "email string" and the author xml, it uses my email for both name and email. I really would like to change the name to my actual name rather than the email.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not currently a way to do this.

Comment: How was it set to begin with?

Comment: The account that created the calendar is the owner.

Comment: Email Google???

Comment: @gadgetmo They're probably too busy taking over the world.

Comment: @Svish Probably.

Comment: @Raystafarian can you post that as an answer? I totally agree that there isn't a way to do this, it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no current way to change the Google calendar owner.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this problem and was able to solve it by editing a contact saved inside [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/). Be sure to check inside the "Other Contacts" folder for a relevant entry.

Another source of the owner name in Google Calendar is said to be the profile name in Google+, but given the format of the unwanted name in question, Google Contacts is surely the culprit as it was for me.

Comment: Works. On the Contact site the bad contact info didn't show in search and I had to scroll to it. It's sorted alphabetically.