# Video shorter than 15 minutes is counting towards Picasa Web storage limit

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I am using Picasa Web and one of the features is that you can have videos that run no more than 15 minutes not be counted in your storage limit:

> If you've signed up for Google+[...] videos up to 15 minutes won't count towards your free storage.

**Source: http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1224181**

I have uploaded a 46 second 1080p video and this is counting as 132mb within my account. If it makes any difference, I have stored the video in a private album.

Why does my short video count against my free limit?

Comment: @Svish You could email Google. [If they're not too busy taking over the world](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/how-to-change-my-name-in-google-calendar#comment18266_19021)

Comment: Are you having a google+ account as well?

Comment: Are you still having those problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the format of the video wasn't supported, see reference [supported video formats](http://support.google.com/picasa/answer/19626?hl=en)

I've asked at the [google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/picasa/Xtu9vX4wS5w/UYvt5l7uKoAJ) and they give the same answer, that up to 15 min. of full HD movie, it doesn't add up to the storage limit.

I've downloaded a full HD test movie in m2ts format (15 MB, 13 seconds) and uploaded it 5 times into my picasa account (with google+, 5 GB storage):
[image]

Before upload:
[image]

After upload:
[image]

As you can see, the storage hasn't increased. Given the fact that your question is more then 1 year old, I would say: do you still face those problems?

Comment: Thanks for testing this out so carefully - I am no longer having this issue :)

Comment: I am having this issue, and my video format it supported.  I've got several videos under 7 minutes in length, and they are taking up 10% of available space! (nothing else is taking any space)